# Is a Chinese visa required for entering Tibet without passing through the rest of China?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, tibet, swedish-citizens

If flying to Tibet through Kathmandu or Hong Kong and **not** setting foot in the rest of China, is a Chinese visa necessary to enter Tibet, or only the Tibet travel permit?

I **do** need a visa for mainland China other than under the 72/144-hour TWOV arrangement, which doesn't apply in Lhasa. Since Tibet has autonomy, however, I wonder whether a Tibet Travel Permit alone would be sufficient?

Comment: I believe the One China Policy includes Tibet as well...

Comment: Unlike Taiwan, Tibet is actually physically controlled by the Chinese government, despite its separatist movement. So same laws apply as any other part of China. Only Taiwan actually is an independent government which China refuses to acknowledge.

Comment: If you go to Tibet, then you **are** setting foot in China. Tibet is a part of China.

Comment: Er, the "Tibet travel permit" he is asking about is issued by the government of China. The question, viewed another way, is whether it "counts" as a visa under Chinese law.

Comment: @Random832 "The question, viewed another way, is whether it "counts" as a visa under Chinese law" I know it doesn't if also visiting other parts of China

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tibet is considered to be inside China, so yes you need a visa for China, plus a Tibet Travel permit.  Tibet does not enjoy the special immigration rules that apply to Hong Kong.